# How to do math operation with an array from mongodb?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, express, ejs

I have an array in mongodb, which contains objects with type of strings. These objects are only numbers but they are saved in mongodb as strings. I want to multiply each elements in the array, but i'm stucked, because when I convert the array elements from string to number, but not multiplying correctly. Here is my code for the array called `quantity`, which is converted from string to numbers:

```html
<div>
      <p>Serving: <input type="number" name="serving" class="serving" step="any" value="2" min="1"></p>
      <input type="hidden" id="previousServing" value="5"/>
</div>

<div>
  <li class="ingredient">
    <% recipe.quantity.forEach(function(quantity, index){
      numarray = parseInt(quantity.toString())
      %>
      <span class="amount" id="amount"><%= numarray %></span>
    <% }) %>
  </li>
</div>
```

Here is my javascript code, where I want to do the math operation with each elements of the array (multiply with any number, what the user adding in textbox):

```js
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('.serving').bind('keyup', function(event) {
      var previousValue = parseInt($("#previousServing").val());
      var newValue = parseInt($(event.target).val());
      if (previousValue && newValue) {
          $('.ingredient').each(function(index, elem) {
              var ingredientNow = $('.amount', elem);
              var oldIngredientAmount = ingredientNow.text();
              var newIngredientAmount = oldIngredientAmount * newValue / previousValue;
              ingredientNow.text(newIngredientAmount);
          });
          $('#previousServing').val(newValue);
      }
  });
});
</script>
```

Where should be the problem? I tested the converted array with `typeoff` and every element was **number**, and the output are random numbers, because when I done the math with the string array, I got an output numbers, but these was incorrect, and doing the same with the converted array.

[image: UPDATE: Here is the array for example in mongodb]

Comment: It's hard to say where the problem is without example data

Comment: I'm edited the question and I added a picture with example data from mongodb. Here is a demo code, which is running, but I modified this with my "quantity" array:
http://jsfiddle.net/0sbdna13/

Comment: You have a mongoDB question, then better put sample data at https://mongoplayground.net/

Comment: "... they are saved in mongodb as strings" - very bad design! Store numeric values as number.

Comment: Good idea, but the easiest way to store the quantity in array, and i can't find out that how to add the type for array to save the quantity numbers in numeric value within the array. Next option could be to store every number in a new document, but i don't want to do like this, in array is much easier i think. The only problem is to do math operation (multiplying) with the array, and I can't find out, how to do this

Comment: You could `"$map"` your text array to a numeric type with `"$toDouble"`, `"$toInt"`, `"$toLong"`, or `"$toDecimal"`.